# Google Maps (JavaScript) markers and shapes don't show up in Android emulator

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, google-maps-api-3

I am creating an Android app using Apache Cordova, and I'm pulling in the Google Maps JavaScript API and hosting the map within an HTML page in the Cordova app's web view. The map displays fine and the controls (zoom, panning, etc.) work fine as well.

Whenever I have any shapes or markers on the map, however, these do not show up in the Android emulator. If I run the app on a connected Android device, they show up exactly as they should.

I have actually seen this happen with a couple of other Cordova apps I've written. Every once in a while, the markers will show up after some time. What might be causing this to happen? Is there some way I could force a redraw of all overlays?

**How to replicate**

1. `cordova create simple-map com.example.simplemap SimpleMap`
2. `cd simple-map`
3. `cordova platform add android@6.3.0 --save`
4. In `www/index.html`, remove the `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" ...>` tag
5. Remove the contents of `<body></body>` and replace it with the following. Be sure to replace `YOUR_API_KEY` with a valid [Google Maps JavaScript API key](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key).

```html
<div id="map"></div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBzUUcYSV0U0lAQhGKTO9Ccq67V_qsy5Lc&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
```

6. Replace the contents of `www/css/index.css` with the following.

```css
#map {
  height: 100%;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

7. Replace the contents of `www/js/index.js` with the following.

```js
var app = {

  map: null,

  init: function init() {
    var position = {
          lat: 43.074698,
          lng: -89.384107
        };

    this.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: position,
      zoom: 12
    });

    new google.maps.Marker({
      position: position,
      map: this.map
    });

    new google.maps.Circle({
      strokeColor: '#aa00ff',
      strokeOpacity: 0.8,
      strokeWeight: 2,
      fillColor: '#9c27b0',
      fillOpacity: 0.35,
      map: this.map,
      center: position,
      radius: 500
    });
  }

};

function initMap() {
  app.init();
}
```

8. `cordova run android`

Comment: Where is your code? Please provide a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with which we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have added code.

Comment: Sorry I am no android / cordova expert. You might want to close this question and open a new one with the same content so it gets some attention.